# How can I pass information between Go pipelines?

Tags: thoughtworks-go

_Hi!

I have a deployable artifact set that gets tested in a pipeline, and this information must be passed to a subsequent deploy pipeline.  Right now, I'm writing this information to a file, but how can the next pipeline read it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behold the article that answers this question: http://support.thoughtworks.com/entries/23754976-Pass-variables-to-other-pipelines